# warning in post route simualtion

Tags: vhdl

here is the warning:

```
                Expected := 1.602 ns; Observed := -960.942 ns; At : 1.231 ns
at 1231 ps(3), Instance /qw/uut/matrixinput_88/ : Warning: /X_FF PULSE

                       WIDTH High VIOLATION ON CLK;
```

What are those values for observed and expected ? what do they mean !? as observed is in a negative value!!

This process code is between

```
if(rising_edge(clk)) then
end if;
```

I just want to know the meaning of these values .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your clock pulse must be at least 1.602ns wide.  The error happened at 1.231ns into the simulation.

The fact that the observed value is -960+ns (ie well before the start of the simulation) makes me think there's a bug in the timing check somewhere!